# Paypal Advanced Integration - Hosted Fields and SCA Integration

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I've integrated Paypal advanced integration using hosted fields but am struggling to see how I can integrate the SCA flow.

According to the following:

https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/card-testing/#link-simulate3dsecurecardpayments

I need to pass in an attribute of SCA_ALWAYS when creating the order. But if I do I have to pass payment source. I am using hosted fields so don't really use a payment source (its created by the hosted fields).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For such payments, specify `"payment_source": { "card": {} }`

There is a v2 version of the [advanced integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/) with example code. Among other differences, it uses the component `card-fields` rather than `hosted-fields`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to pass the parameter but I still can't seem to trigger the SCA workflow. My order just gets approved straight away!

Comment: You're using one of the 3ds test cards?

Comment: Yes from this page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/customize/3d-secure/test/

Comment: liability_shift in the response and in the first parameter of onApprove should vary

Comment: OK so realised that I was using 3DS2 cards where no flow kicks in. But it does for 3DS1. Does Paypal handle 3DS2 automatically, or is there a different flow for it?

Comment: So anybody else that comes here in the future this is a valid test card: 5232106671708398